# instant search for website

Tags: php, search, instant

I need to arrange instant search for my website (like google instant).
When the user is typing, the script should suggest results.
As I understood I need php+html+javascript.
Any suggestions, or link or something helpfull?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done using AJAX. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp

Comment: I tryed it, created index.html, livesearch.php and links.xml.. First error what I met while typing was: Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: Start tag expected, '<' not found in... then I edited links.xml, added <xml></xml>

Comment: know while typing I see "no suggestions"

Comment: That was just as a simple example of the idea, in your real aplication you wouldnt search using xml, but search maybe in your database. I posted that just to point you out in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that you need crazy amount of indexing. You need to index almost every keyword and store search results for each keyword. There is no way you can do a live search on database that fast. Once you have good index you can use .keypress function of JQuery to detect if user is typing something, once user types something you can send the search query to the server and fetch the result and display using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You should set tags for each article, or ex. search in every category on your site.

Example code for the front-end:

```
        // index.html

        // ajax
        <script type="text/javascript">  
            function loadXML(query) {
                $.ajax({  
                    type: "POST",  
                    data: ({ajaxSearch : query.value}),  
                    url: 'search.php',
                    success: function(data) {  
                        $('#searchcontainer').html(data);  
                    }  
                }); 
        </script>

        // html
        <input type="text" id="ajaxSearch" onkeyup="loadXML(this);" />
        <div id="searchcontainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with jQuery UI Autocomplete. It's easy to setup and fairly easy to implement what you're after:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

The data for the search will be in an array of strings, like

```
[ "tag1", "tag2", "tag3" ... ]
```

so you'll need to do a database query (or setup manual search terms) and populate your array based on that.